# Click events not being fired in PhoneGap / Backbone.js with Underscore.js template

Tags: iphone, cordova, backbone.js, underscore.js, cordova-2.0.0

I have been making a Phonegap / Cordova 2.0 app with backbone.js which has all been fine until I tried to build in a form. The form is displayed but the click events do not trigger the keyboard.

I played around with different events and found that adding `ontouchstart="this.focus()"` brought up the keyboard fine. I added a catchall in the view function to bring focus:

```
window.PageView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template(tpl.get('page'));
    },

    render: function(eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        $('input', $(this.el)).bind('touchstart',function(event) {
            $(this).focus();
        });
        return this;
    }

});
```

But even with this if I change `bind('touchstart'...` to `'click'` it doesn't get triggered.

I have found a couple of other posts like: [click event doesn't fire in an underscore template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543948/click-event-doesnt-fire-in-an-underscore-template)

which suggests it is to do with the underscore.js templating process but nothing is very clear.

I guess I could make a timer function on touchstart to simulate this but it's kindof mysterious so I want to know what's going on really.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was iScroll causing the problem.

```
            onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) { e.preventDefault(); },
```

Specifically. I just commented out the `e.preventDefault();` and it worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.$(':input').bind(...)
```

Comment: Binding events isn't the problem as I can bind other events successfully. It just doesn't trigger the click event.